# Ionic 3 sorting Pipe JSON by featured property

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Could someone help me make a pipe that sorts an array based on the c`ustom_fields.featured` property?

```
<div *ngFor="let ev of list | featured; let p = index">
    <ion-item>
       <p>{{ev.custom_fields.featured}}</p>
    </ion-item>
</div>
```

I want the ones where featured is "yes" to come first, like yes,yes,yes,no,no,..... etc . Thank you.

```
{
  id: 49901,
  url: "https://pasabon.com/ajde_events/incredibles-2-2d-2/",
  title: "Incredibles 2 (2D)",
  content: "<p>Bob Parr (Mr. Incredible) is left to care for Jack-Jack while 
  Helen(Elastigirl) is out saving the world. < /p> ",
  excerpt: -[
    "Sat. and Sun. matinee: 12:45"
  ],
  tags: [],
  custom_fields: -{
    evcal_repeat: "yes",
    evcal_srow: 1536120001,
    evcal_erow: 1536206399,
    evcal_lmlink: null,
    evcal_subtitle: -[
      "Sat. and Sun. matinee: 12:45"
    ],
    featured: "no",
    evcal_lat: "12.106403",
    evcal_lon: "-68.938801"
  },
}
```

Comment: share featured pipe code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe ({
   name : 'featured'
})
export class FeaturedPipe implements PipeTransform {

  compare(a: any , b: any) {
    if (a.featured < b.featured)
      return 1;
    if (a.featured > b.featured)
      return -1;
    return 0;
  }

  transform(input: Array<any>) : Array<any> {
    return input.sort(this.compare);
  }
}
```